# Erro "Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server' did not find a matching property"

Tags: java, tomcat

Eu preciso de ajuda para resolver os problemas que aparecem no registro de log:

> Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ApasiSpringMVC' did not find a matching property.

Log completo:

> ```
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
> ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} ***Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ApasiSpringMVC' did not find a matching property.***
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.44
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          May 10 2017 17:21:09 UTC
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.0.44.0
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 10
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            10.0
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_172-b11
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\FÁBIO\workspace003\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\FÁBIO\Documents\apache-tomcat-8.0
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\FÁBIO\workspace003\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\FÁBIO\Documents\apache-tomcat-8.0
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\FÁBIO\workspace003\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\FÁBIO\Documents\apache-tomcat-8.0\endorsed
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
> INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\;C:\Users\FÁBIO\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\FÁBIO\Documents\eclipse-jee-mars;;.
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
> INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
> INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
> INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
> INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
> INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 799 ms
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
> INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
> INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.44
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:21 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
> INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
> INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
> INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
> INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
> jul 20, 2018 5:17:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
> INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 2405 ms
> ```

Comment: Este site está em português, não em inglês. Já traduzi a sua pergunta.

Comment: Ok, eu vi minutos depois que postei. Obrigado!

Comment: Preciso de ajuda na primeira linha do código.

Comment: ***Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ApasiSpringMVC' did not find a matching property.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O arquivo `server.xml` do Tomcat contém um atributo chamado `source`. O Tomcat não entende o que é esse atributo e por causa disso lança essa *warning* (advertência). Isso não é um erro, é apenas uma mensagem chata que o Tomcat coloca por causa desse probleminha.

O atributo `source` é tipicamente adicionado de forma automática pelo Eclipse para que ele saiba como executar o projeto web no Tomcat.

Uma forma que talvez faça essa mensagem sumir, seria ir na configuração do eclipse, nas opções do servidor e marcar a opção "*Publish module contents to separate XML files*".

Enfim, isso é apenas o Eclipse sendo o Eclipse!

Fontes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4278009/540552
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3566146/540552
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366404/540552
- http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/11/29/warning-setpropertiesruleserverserviceenginehostcontext-setting-property/